# Magento 2 override /lib html file

Tags: magento2, overrides, gallery-image, lib

I am trying to override an html file in the lib folder, but I cant get it to work. Here is what I have so far:

Path to file I want to override: `/lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.html`

Path to file I want to override with: `/app/design/frontend/{Module}/{Theme}/web/mage/gallery/gallery.html`

I have flushed the cache, but it still only loads the original file.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Update:
If I delete the lib files, it will use the files I want to use, but I want to override the lib files, not have to delete them.

Comment: Need to disable Browser cache or try to use Incognito mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed something with clearing cache.

Copy file to

```
 /app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/web/mage/gallery/gallery.html
```

1. Clear cache and delete pub/static/frontend
2. Deploy static content (if you in production mode)
3. Clear browser cache.